# SMTP virtual server doesn't show in MMC and in IIS

Tags: iis-7, smtp

I installed a Windows 2008 r2 feature - SMTP server.  All seemed OK and it shows in the list of server features installed.

Now I need to configure it (let's say a port or name) and I don't see SMTP virtual server item in IIS 7 or in MMC.  And of cause it doesn't work when I tried to test it with telnet.

Please help.  How to get the thing working so I could see its propeties in IIS?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This really probably belongs on [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com). That said, the SMTP serivce configuration stuff never was migrated to the IIS 7[.5] administration tools. You should be able to access the configuration option through Start -> Administrative Tools -> Internet Information Services (IIS) 6.0 Manager.

Comment: Oh, my. Thanks a lot. I was banging my head aganst iis 7.  What is the default smtp server name if my "fully qualified domain name" is CL-RR-45612CN?  Is it, smtp.CL-RR-45612CN ?

Comment: To quote Microsoft: "... You cannot manage an IIS 7.5 Web or FTP Server by using Internet Information Services (6.0) Manager."

Comment: @Andrew: Not sure I see the relevance. You cannot manage IIS 7 or 7.5 with the version 6 tools, but the SMTP Server is still the version run on IIS 6 and requires the IIS 6 manager.

Comment: @Val: This is probably way too late, but it's just the fully qualified domain name for your server, i.e., CL-RR-45612CN.

Comment: You can start IIS 6 Manager manually - run: c:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\InetMgr6.exe